# Routing not based on roles

Tags: laravel, closures, middleware

Laravel 5.5 question.

Let say the user is already authenticated and have the correct access role however you want them to perform an action on a particular page before they can visit any other routes.

How do you prevent them from visiting the other routes until they have performed a specific action on a particular page?

Because putting in the other routes in the address bar bypass the action required page.

Example 
You have 3 routes after login
1. /a1
2. /a2
3. /a3

If user doesn't perform an action on some route /billing they shouldn't see 1, 2, 3. However I noticed if user already knows 1-3 and they enter in the address bar it takes them there.

Comment: Set yourself up a middleware to check whether step 1 is actioned and then wrap a grouped route around all of the authenticated routes.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, I believe the proposed solution will work, I was playing around with middlewares yesterday but wasn't sure I had to call them on all the group of routes. I'll implement this tonight and confirm it works.

Comment: No problem at all. I have used this myself on a number of projects and can confirm if done correctly it will work very well for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a basic example of my comment above. Yours will need to be tweaked accordingly to suit your needs as mine is relevant to a game project:

Middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        if ($user->game_path == 0)
        {
            Session::flash('error', 'Your player path must be selected before continuing.');

            return redirect('/');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Kernel:

```
'path' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckPath::class,
```

Route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['path']], function () {

   Route::get('/online', 'VariousController@online')->name('online');
});
```

Basically, if a player is trying to view /online but their path == 0 it'll redirect them back to the desired page for them to choose/update.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much @Option

Comment: You're most welcome. If this answer satisfies your needs please mark it so that other users with a similar problem know which answer to look at.